# I am try to add a admin panel to upload videos on my movie streaming website

Tags: php, sql, xampp

So I have created a `streaming` website and I want to create an `admin panel` so that admin can add a preview, a thumbnail, the category and the main video to the database. I tried in this way but this isn't working so any suggestions where I might be going wrong?
The error I am getting is "Notice : Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in adminhandler.php on line 33"

**admin.php**

```
<?php 
include("config.php");`enter code here`
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ShortFilm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Content Starts -->
    <div class="admin-box">
      <form action="adminHandler.php" method="POST" class="admin-box-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3 class="admin-box-title">Add Movie</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Movie Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter movie name" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="category_id">Movie Genre</label>
          <input type="number" name="category_id" id="category_id" placeholder="Enter movie genre" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="thumbnail">Movie Cover</label>
          <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="preview">Movie Preview</label>
          <input type="file" name="preview" id="preview" required/>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="filePath">Movie File</label>
          <input type="file" name="filePath" id="filePath" required/>
        </div> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="admin_form" value="Submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**adminhandler.php**

```
<?php


    // Change the upload limits in php.ini
    // ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');
    // ini_set('post_max_size', '50M');
    // ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
    // ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

    if (isset($_POST['admin_form'])) {
        include 'config.php';

        // File Targets
        $targetCover = "../entities/thumbnail/" . basename($_FILES['thumbnail']['name']);
        $targetMovie = "../entities/previews/" . basename($_FILES['preview']['name']);

        // Store in DB
        $name = strtolower($_POST['name']);
        $category= strtolower($_POST['categoryId']);
        $thumbnail = "entities/thumbnail/" . basename($_FILES['thumbnail']['name']);
        $filePath = "entities/previews/" . basename($_FILES['preview']['name']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO entities(name, thumbnail, preview, categoryId) VALUES('$name','$thumbnail', '$filePath','$category')";
       

        $result = $con -> query($sql);

        if ($result && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumbnail']['name'], $targetCover) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['preview']['name'], $targetMovie)) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Movie Added Successfully! Press OK to Redirect to Admin Page.')</script>";
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="admin.php"</script>';
        }
        else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(`Error Uploading Movie! Press Try Again.\n{$con -> error}`)</script>";            
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="admin.php"</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```

**Database Tables**
[image]

enter code here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please try to clarify what `"this isn't working"` actually means as it gives no clue as to what  the nature of the problem is. What have you done to debug this problem? Do you get errors? What does and does not happen?

Comment: Incidentally your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection - never take user input for granted. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Check `move_uploaded_file` documentation here: https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file
It seems that you provided wrong parameters. It should be `$_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name']` etc.

Comment: I changed some code and now the error I am getting is Notice : Trying to get property 'error' of non-object in adminhandler.php on line 33